# How do you make a modal QDialog impossible to close via user input

Tags: qt, modal-dialog

I have a QDialog which i'd like to be modal, i.e. I'd like the user to be locked out of the GUI completely until I programatically hide the dialog.

Here is a small reproducible example:

```
QDialog *dialog = new QDialog(this, Qt::Splashscreen);
dialog->setModal(true);
dialog->setWindowModality(Qt::ApplicationModal);
dialog->exec();
```

This is easily closed by clicking outside of the dialog.

Pressing the `esc` key would also close the dialog however in my custom implementation I am catching the event and dealing with it separately.

### Edits

This only seems to occur on Windows, on Linux it behaves as desired.

Pressing `alt + F4`also closes the dialog regardless of catching key events.

Comment: Just override `closeEvent()` and ignore the event?

Comment: @peppe I need to close it eventually though, I guess I could store some state that allowed the close event once some value had been set.

Comment: Of course, sure. You can do the checks you want in `closeEvent()` and accept/ignore it conditionally.

Comment: @peppe Even catching the close event doesn't prevent `ctrl+F4` from closing it.

Comment: Change the window flags to remove the close button. this will work on windows.

Comment: @Felix There already isn't a close button... Oh, I forgot to include flag in the constructor...